# How to add levels corresponding to a subset/range of values in a column of a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a column with over 600 factors, but I want to reduce this to 7 factors/levels by taking a range of values in the column and grouping them into the factors. However, the factors are a bit strange--they are coded as character values "01", "02" .... "600", with the last one having an "E" in front of the numbers (E200 for example). I want to group these 0-100, 101-200, ..., 501-600, E, in order to make 7 factors for this column. I know to take and condense certain elements of a column to factor to create new levels, for example:

```
levels(df$col)<- list("foo" ="foo", "bar"= c("bar","c","d"))
```

How would I go about doing this? I want to try something like:

```
df$col <- as.numeric(df$col) # cannot coerce due to "E"
levels(df$col) <- list("1-100" = c(subset(df[,col] >= 1 && df[,col] <= 100)), "101-200" = c(subset(df[,col] >= 101 && df[,col] <= 200)),
 ........, "501-600" = c(subset(df[,col] >= 501 && df[,col] <= 600)), "E" = ???)
df$col <- as.factor(df$col)
```

But obviously I cannot coerce as.numeric to df because of the one factor that has an "E" in front of it. Is there an easier way to go about this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

MCVE:

```
structure(list(gender_house_purchaser = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female"), house_code = c("250.83", "276", "548", "8", "197", 
"414", "434", "428", "428", "199", "410", "410", "572", "E57", 
"189", "586", "427", "277", "428", "584"), num_rooms = c(1L, 
9L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 
6L, 8L, 9L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: have you tried `df$col <- as.numeric(gsub("E", "", df$col))` ?

Comment: I think I answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Perhaps two steps: first convert just the possible numerics into their ranges and then convert the remaining "E"-levels

```
 dfrm$temp[ is.numeric(dfrm$temp) ] <- 
        factor( c('0-100', '101-200', '...', '501-600')[
                     findInterval(dfrm$temp,  c(0,100, 200, 500, 600) ) ])
 dfrm$temp[ grepl("E", dfrm$house_code) ] <- "E"
 dfrm$temp <- factor(dfrm$temp)
 #------------------------------
dfrm
   gender_house_purchaser house_code num_rooms    temp
1                  Female     250.83         1     ...
2                  Female        276         9     ...
3                  Female        548         6 501-600
4                    Male          8         7   0-100
5                    Male        197         5 101-200
6                    Male        414         7     ...
7                  Female        434         8     ...
8                  Female        428         8     ...
9                    Male        428         8     ...
10                   Male        199         9 101-200
11                   Male        410         8     ...
12                 Female        410         7     ...
13                   Male        572         6 501-600
14                 Female        E57         8       E
15                 Female        189         6 101-200
16                 Female        586         3 501-600
17                   Male        427         7     ...
18                   Male        277         6     ...
19                 Female        428         8     ...
20                 Female        584         9 501-600
```

You did make an almost complete example, but you left in the ellipsis in the specification of ranges. I'm mildly annoyed when people do that, so I acted out my petty annoyance by leaving the ellipsis in to let you see the logical consequences.

I realized also that I had gotten tangled up in my efforts to use `levels<-` so I switched to working with character values before finally `factor()`-ing the result.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your suggestion for factoring "E" with grepl() worked for factoring every regular expression starting with "E" into its own level, but the code for the is.numeric() portion seemed to not work. I tried splitting it up, for example like so: `levels(df$col)[findInterval(levels(df$col)[ is.numeric(df$col) ], c(0,100))] <- "0-100"` but it did not group all of the values in that range into a single "0-100" level, instead they were still their own individual levels "10", "11", "12", etc.

Comment: So rather than posting a MCVE you decided to make revisions of untested code and that didn't work. My response is "no surprise there". Maybe if I repeated that suggestion you will pay attention?  [MCVE] ... [MCVE] ... [MCVE]

Comment: sorry, my mistake. You're right. I haven't done an MCVE before, but just I edited it with an included MCVE for testing. I want to try to group "house_code" into factors according to the range of values listed above. Much appreciated.

Comment: The advantages of asking for a MCVE include 1) the possibility that doing so will allow you to solve the problem on your own (as often happens when I have a question), 2) clarity regarding the data types under consideration, 3) increased willingness of potential "answers" to start the coding and debugging process, and 4) increased value of the Q&A to be of use to future searchers on SO and Google.